# Populating disjoint ranges with google sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

Unfortunately, no one replied to my post, so I am reposting.
Right now, I have data in the form

```
{
   user: {user: 'fdafa', week1: '1', week2: '2'}
}
```

and for all users it's like that

In my spreadsheet (through google sheets API), I want to get the data to display with the users as the very first column, then there's a column for total score (which comes as the sum of the cells where I want the week scores to go), and then there's the week scores. In other words, I need the data to fill the sheet, with a column between the user and scores for the total score to go.

Unfortunately disjoint ranges don't work (from what I've heard, but I haven't actually tested it), so could someone help me with this?

Comment: Alternative question has been deleted.